# Temp table in sql

Tags: sql-server

what is

CREATE TABLE #Inventory( )  in sql ? and how its work with store procedure ?

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly assumed, it's a temporary table.

See a discussion [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447115/temporary-table-usage-in-sql-server) for some more info.

And they work just fine in stored procedures.

Answer (score -1):

CREATE TABLE #Inventory
(
  InventoryID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
, InventoryName varchar(100)
)
GO

Comment: This has absolutely no value as an answer to the question. Try to explain a little, or give some helpfull links to the answer/documentation that can help.